# Xamarin Forms Binding not showing on ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to bind my ViewModel to the View but I couldn't do it yet.

Here's the code.

(Model)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Identificacao { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Observable Model)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class ObservableProduto : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Produto produto;
        public ObservableProduto()
        {
            produto = new Produto()
            {
                Identificacao = "Primeiro",
                Codigo = "123456"

            };
            produto = new Produto()
            {
                Identificacao = "Segundo",
                Codigo = "123456"

            };
            produto = new Produto()
            {
                Identificacao = "Terceiro",
                Codigo = "123456"

            };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Codigo
        {               
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Codigo, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    produto.Codigo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Codigo");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Codigo;
            }
        }

        public string Identificacao
        {
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Identificacao, StringComparison.Ordinal)) 
                {
                    produto.Identificacao = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Identificacao");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Identificacao;
            }
        }

        public string Tipo
        {
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Tipo, StringComparison.Ordinal)) 
                {
                    produto.Tipo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Tipo");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Tipo;
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler == null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(ViewModel)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class ListProdutoViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto> produtos;

        public ListProdutoViewModel()
        {
            produtos = new ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto> Produtos
        {
            set
            {
                if (value != produtos)
                {
                    produtos = value;
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produtos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(View)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CadastroProdutos;"
    x:Class="CadastroProdutos.ListProduto"
    Title="Listagem de Produtos">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20,40,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Produtos}">
            <ListView.BindingContext>
                <local:ListProdutoViewModel />
            </ListView.BindingContext>
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Label Text="Produtos" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Identificacao}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

It not worked, It didn't show those elements on the list. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your ObservableProduto is wrong and only contains 1 Produto (and not 3 as written in your constructor)... And you don't need a get/set for your ObservableCollection as it is already created in your constructor ... but it won't solve your problem anyway ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite understanding the MVVM approach, but you're almost there. You don't need to have the `ObservableProduto` class. You can make your `Produto` class your model.

This is your `Produto` model. I went ahead and changed it up for you.

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class Produto : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string codigo;
        public string Codigo 
        { 
            get {return codigo;} 
            set {codigo=value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string identificacao;
        public string Identificacao 
        { 
            get {return identificacao;} 
            set {identificacao=value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string tipo ;
        public string Tipo 
        { 
            get {return tipo;} 
            set {tipo=value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You should contain an `ObservableCollection` of your `Produto`s in a viewmodel. I see you've done that. I've edited it a bit. You may need to be careful about totally resetting your `ObservableCollection` on a set.

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class ListProdutoViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<Produto> produtos;

        public ListProdutoViewModel()
        {
            produtos = new ObservableCollection<Produto>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Produto> Produtos
        {
            set
            {
                if (value != produtos)
                {
                    produtos = value;
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produtos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: you will need to add items to your `ObservableColleciton` still.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Got an error after those changes "Object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.TextCell' cannot be converted to type 'Xamarin.Forms.View'"

Comment: That's because you have a `TextCell` located within a `StackLayout`. Remove the `StackLayout`. You just need the `TextCell`. Everything a `ListView` displays needs to be some form of Cell or inherit from `ViewCell` and everything a `StackLayout` displays needs to be some form of `View`.